# Return sqlite DB without case sensitivity

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm sitting here wondering how to sort my database without case sensitivity.
Let's say I have 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b'. It will print like this: 'A', 'B', 'a', 'b'. but I want it sorted in a more human way.
Here's my Cursor function:

```
/**
* Return a Cursor over the list of all brands in the database
* 
* @return Cursor over all brands sorted alphabetically 
+ TODO: doesn't sort alphabetically because it's case sensitive
*/
public Cursor fetchAllBrands() {

return mDb.query(Constants.DATABASE_TABLE, 
    new String[] { 
        Constants.KEY_ROWID, Constants.KEY_BRAND, Constants.KEY_STOCK 
    }, 
    null, null, null, null, Constants.KEY_BRAND);
}
```

I have noticed that Java has `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, but I have no idea how to implement it if that is the solution to this problem.
Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958039/sqlite-query-in-non-case-sensitive-alphabetical-order).
Unfortunately is seems that you have to use the `rawQuery()` method instead of using the `query()` wrapper method. This method allows you to input raw SQL code that will be executed like so ...

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT " + Constants.KEY_ROWID + "," + Constants.KEY_BRAND + "," +
             Constants.KEY_STOCK +
           " FROM " + Constants.DATABASE_TABLE +
           " ORDER BY " + Constants.KEY_BRAND + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC;", null);
```

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to use rawQuery. But I guess that's what I'll have to do. Thanks for the reply - I'll test it when I get home in some hours.

Answer (score 3):

Try a `rawQuery(...)` using `COLLATE NOCASE`. Example...

```
return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + Constants.KEY_ROWID + ","
              + Constants.KEY_BRAND + ","
              +  Constants.KEY_STOCK
              + " FROM " + Constants.DATABASE_TABLE
              + " ORDER BY " + Constants.KEY_BRAND + " COLLATE NOCASE", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
public Cursor fetchAllBrands() {

return mDb.query(Constants.DATABASE_TABLE, 
new String[] { 
    Constants.KEY_ROWID, Constants.KEY_BRAND, Constants.KEY_STOCK 
}, 
null, null, null, null, Constants.KEY_BRAND + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
}
```