# why won't my arraylist sort work?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

the list has two names (Diego and Alan) it always shows Diego first
I have already tried many different things but none of them seems to work

```
public void mostrarusuarios() {
    inicializarbase();
    if (responder == true) {
        Cursor cursor = basededatos.rawQuery("select * from Usuarios ", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            listusers.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("User")));
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                listusers.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("User")));
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listusers.size(); i++) {
        Toast.makeText(this, listusers.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    basededatos.close();
}

public void orderalphabetically() {
    showusers();
    Collections.sort(listusers, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    for (int i = 0; i < listusers.size(); i++) {
        Toast.makeText(this, listusers.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just ORDER BY in your sqlite query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958039/sqlite-query-in-non-case-sensitive-alphabetical-order

Comment: Also, don't Toast in a loop if you want to see the actual order of the list

Comment: I indented your code. It was making my brain hurt, and my eyes bleed. Consider `do { listusers.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("User"))); } while (cursor.moveToNext());`, it won't solve your problem but see my previous sentence.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes but by doing so I'd have to do all that again because I need just the way I get it in there and sorted alphabetically

Comment: @cricket_007 how should I Toast?

Comment: Don't Toast. Use `Log` instead. And no, if you query it ordered, you never need to sort